# Schema for telephone

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I want to use Schema on my website. What structure will suit most, if I describe the general data relating to a specific number? What structure do I get for writing

**schema/Place** or **schema/AdministrativeArea** or **schema/Organization** or **schema.org/Person**?

I guess that no **schema/Person**, nor **schema/Organization** not suitable. Since we do not relate specifically to them general information. But we have a particular connection to the place, so I think it fits **schema/Place**? I also think we can use **schema/CreativeWork**, but we have structured information, so I'd like to use something more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`telephone`](http://schema.org/telephone) property is for providing the telephone number of a `ContactPoint`, `Organization`, `Person`, or `Place` (as of [version 2.2](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.2)).

It expects *Text* as value (and [in the future maybe *URL*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30735286/1591669), too). So if you want to follow that advice, you can’t directly provide structured data *about* the telephone number in Schema.org.

Related: If you provide a `ContactPoint` item, you can provide the  [`contactOption`](http://schema.org/contactOption) property (e.g., for specifying that the telephone number is toll free) and the [`areaServed`](http://schema.org/areaServed) property (should you want to restrict where you provide your service).

Comment: But separate use ContactPoint leads to an error in developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Comment: @Zhenya40: If you need help with that, you could create a new question (which must include a minimal example of your markup that gives this error).